# Trouble granting access to AD Groups to connect to an Azure SQL Server/Database

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, database-permissions

So I've created an Azure SQL server and have a couple of databases under that server. My main goal is to allow access to a couple other AD (Entra now?) groups to a database under the server. I don't really care if they have access to all databases under the server, but they really only need one.

I've created users for these groups under master and under the specific database that they need.

```
CREATE USER "ADGroup" FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

Also provided them with read access under the database, by giving them the db_reader role.

I got word that when they tried to connect, they couldn't. So I tried

```
Grant connect to ADGroup;
```

under the master database. I was told that I didn't have GRANT permissions and was a little confused, but come to find out, server level permissions aren't a thing in Azure SQL apparently? (First paragraph on this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16) )

So I've granted connect under the specific database, and that executed successfully. I haven't heard back from them yet, but are they going to be able to connect? Wouldn't the server NEED to know that they're allowed to connect in the first place? If this won't work, how should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create an Azure AD group using Azure Portal and then add members to that group. You are correct about creating a user for the group on the specific database you want the group to have access.

```
CREATE USER [SQLGroup] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER
```

For the above T-SQL to execute successfully you need to be connected to the database as Azure Active Directory Admin User.

Now, make sure you assigned read-only permissions to the group as following:

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', 'SQLGroup'
```

After that, any member of the group should be able to connect and query the database without any issues. You can test that using Azure Data Studio or SQL Server Management Studio.

For more information, please read [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/logins-create-manage?view=azuresql).

Comment: Unfortunately this is exactly what I did, but the server will not let them connect. Is there a way to connect to the database directly? Without going through a server connection? I've never done it, but maybe it's possible. Also I've only been told by one person, it's possible they've done something wrong on their end, but I doubt it. And I have no way of being able to test it myself.

Comment: Please share with us any errors you the users receive.

Comment: Well, since I haven't heard back, instead I've created another SQL login under master, and added the user to a database. Gave it read permissions and tried to login with it and I'm getting this error ``` The server principal "test" is not able to access this database "master" under the current security context." ```

Comment: UPDATE: After clicking options and typing in the name of the database, I was able to connect. Is there any way to let them just access the entire server rather than typing in a specific database?

Comment: So they were trying to connect to the master database. That was the issue. Wonderful!

Comment: Only the permissions that are held by fixed server-level roles can propagate from server-level to database permissions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/security-server-roles?view=azuresql#fixed-server-level-roles. On Azure SQL you cannot create a custom role at server-level that propagates permissions to all databases.